# Inject ILogger when registering HttpClient in Asp.Net Core 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

In Asp.Net Core when you register a custom service, like:

```
services.AddScoped<ISomeService, SomeService>();
```

Then, out of the box you can access the Microsoft ILogger from the contractor of SomeService class.

But if you register a custom HttpClient, like:

```
            services.AddHttpClient<ISomeHttpClient, SomeHttpClient>(client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["Url"]);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            });
```

Then, you cannot access the Microsoft ILogger from the constructor of SomeHttpClient. I get the error:

*Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger'*

I am aware that the framework is already logging HttpRequest activity for you. What I would like to do is to log the body of every single request in case the StatusCode is not successful.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use `ILogger<SomeHttpClient> logger` than using `ILogger` directly?

Here is some code which does it and working properly.

```
public class GitHubService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly ILogger<GitHubService> _logger;

    public GitHubService(HttpClient client, ILogger<GitHubService> logger)
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/");
        // GitHub API versioning
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept",
            "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
        // GitHub requires a user-agent
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
            "HttpClientFactory-Sample");

        _client = client;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAspNetDocsIssues()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Getting issues from GitHub");
        return await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<string>>(
            "/repos/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues?state=open&sort=created&direction=desc");
    }
}
```

Source code : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: I definably made the mistake of trying to inject the non-generic version of ILogger. Another way to go is to create a custom DelegatingHandler to encapsulate the logging responsability. Then we can register the handler with services.AddTransient<CustomHandler>() and .AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomHandler>()